# Compile error on constructor using pointer to constant c-string

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors, most-vexing-parse

Can somebody explain why I can compile and run this

```
    T t1( T2( "TEST") );
    t1.print();
```

but not this

```
    const char * TEST_STRING = "TEST";
    T t1( T2( TEST_STRING ) );
    t1.print();
```

The 2nd blocks show

> error: request for member ‘print’ in ‘t1’, which is of non-class type ‘T(T2)’

The classes are as follow

```
class T2 {
public:
    T2( const char * str ) {
        m_str = str;
    }

    void test() const {
        cout << "t2 test" << m_str << endl;
    }
private:
    const char * m_str;
};

class T {
public:
    T( const T2 & t2 ) {
        t2.test();
    }

    void print() {
        cout << "t print " << endl;
    }
};
```

my g++ version is

> g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609

Thank you

Comment: Look up "most vexing parse".

Comment: It's "most vexing parse", quick fix change ( and ) to { and }

Comment: Thank you. @RichardCritten how should I fix this if my compiler does not support initializer lists?
simply create T2 first then pass it through t1 constructor like
const char * TEST_STRING = "TEST";
T2 t2( TEST_STRING );
T t1( t2 );

Comment: Another workaround: `T t1( static_cast<T2>( TEST_STRING ) );`

Comment: Or just: `T t1(( T2(TEST_STRING) ));` (Extra parentheses are allowed around a declarator, but not around a full function parameter, so that can't possibly mean a function declaration.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to all the comments from [immibis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106104/immibis), [Richard Critten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3370124/richard-critten), [aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640/aschepler) and [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

The problem is because

```
T t1( T2( TEST_STRING ) );
```

can be interpreted as

1. a function declaration for a function name t1 that take T2 as an argument and return T
2. a variable definition of t1 of class T, initialized with anonymous instance of class T2.

and it is interpreted as the function declaration.

two possible clean fixes, from [aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640/aschepler)

> Another workaround: `T t1( static_cast<T2>( TEST_STRING ) );`
>
> Or just: `T t1(( T2(TEST_STRING) ));` (Extra parentheses are allowed
>   around a declarator, but not around a full function parameter, so that
>   can't possibly mean a function declaration.)